# Run commands in a nested shell

Tags: shell

Have a shell script that executes another shell script.

Once the second shell script starts runing, i need to execute some commands and finally exit the second shell

Once inside the parent shell , carry on downstream processing. How do I achieve this  ?

```
Parent.sh
   Child.sh
      Command1
      Command2
      exit
Parent Command1
Parent Command2
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Command1` and `Command2` just be part of `Child.sh`? Are `Parent Command1` and `Parent Command2` part of `Parent.sh` or are they to be executed after `Parent.sh` completes?

Comment: Command1 and Command2 are not part of child.sh , child.sh gives me a shell where i need to execute Command1 and Command2. Parent Command 1 and ParentCommand2 are a part of Parent.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how Child.sh is implemented, perhaps:

```
Child.sh <<END
command1
command2
exit
END
```

Otherwise, you might need to use [expect](/questions/tagged/expect)

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine :-) Or maybe better! I have no idea what is required!

Answer (score 0):

Parent:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Parent: I am the parent
child
echo Parent: Performing Command1
echo Parent: Performing Command2
```

Child:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Child: running and about to perform command1 and command2 in subshell
(command1; command2)
echo Child: command1 and command2 complete
```

Comment: Child.sh gives me a shell where I need to run ChildCommand1 and ChildCommand2

Comment: Thanks Mark, but that still doesnt solve my problem, if i run the child.sh in the xterm, it will give me another shell where I need to execute child Command1 and child command2

Comment: You are confusing me (and others, I suspect). Maybe you can differentiate between commands you want the script to run and commands you want to type into a terminal yourself.

Comment: all the commands need to be scripted ,but Command1 and Command2 need to be executed within the shell spawned by Child.sh and then the shell needs to be exited , to continue execution in the parent shell

Comment: Updated, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

parent.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Parent
. ./child.sh
echo "this won't be executed"
```

child.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Child
exit
```

Comment: Child.sh gives a shell , in which child command1 and child commad 2 needs to be executed